# Ignoring property in a class for response resource - Openrasta

Tags: c#, serialization, properties, openrasta

I'm using Openrasta framework. I've simple POCO which is used in my API and this will be sent as ResponseResource to client. It looks like below:

```
Public class User
{
  Public int Id { get; set; }
  Public string Name { get; set; }
  Public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

When sending response to user I dont want to send property "Id" back to the user. How can I make openrasta serialzers to ignore this property? I tried putting XmlIgnore attribute for this property but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which serialization codec? json? xml? xmldatacontract?

Comment: @Marc: Both json and xml

Comment: which xml ;p it supports 2, and it matters...

Comment: sorry for not to be specific. This is not xmlserializer, I'm using XmlDataContract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `[XmlIgnore]` isn't working, I am *guessing* you are using either the [Json](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta/wiki/Doc/Codecs/JsonDataContracts) or [XmlDataContract](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta/wiki/Doc/Codecs/XmlDataContracts) codecs. These are based on `DataContractSerializer`, in which case the mechanism to control the serialization is to mark the type as `[DataContract]`, at which point inclusion becomes ***opt in*** rather than automatic, i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
  public  int Id { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Code { get; set; }
}
```